# When to double rest API routes for the same resource?

Tags: angular, rest, api, django-rest-framework, single-page-application

I need to access `Task` resource by `id` and by `state`. I have two options to achieve this:

**Option 1:**

Create 2 routes:

- `api/tasks/:id`: returns one element
- `api/tasks/:state`: returns a list

**Option 2:**

- Create only 1 root: `api/tasks/:id`
- Get a list of task ids classified by state from a parent ressource: `api/projects/:id`

I am working on a SPA and need to know which option would be cleaner?

Comment: What about using query parameters like `api/tasks?state=STATE` to request a collection of tasks in a specific state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider the following:

- `GET /api/tasks/{id}`: Returns a representation of the task with the given identifier. If no tasks match the given id, a `404` response should be returned.
- `GET /api/tasks?state={state}`: Returns a representation of a collection with the tasks that match the given state. If no tasks match the given state, a `200` response with an empty array should be returned.

Comment: What if I have 5 ressources like "task" and each ressource needs to be accessed by 2 attributes other than "id", Isn't better in this case to go for option 2. This way we write less code (5x2 routes less) and project route serves as index to returns ids of ressources indexed by nedded attributes ?

Comment: @user2080105 I'm not sure what you mean with _"5 resources like 'task'"_. But if you have different resources, you need different URLs.

Comment: like "task" means ressources that are children of "project" and that need to be accecssed by "id" and by "state"

Comment: @user2080105 If a task depends on a project, that is, a task cannot exist without a project, you can use: `/api/projects/{project-id}/tasks/{task-id}`.

Comment: Why not make project route returns tasks rather than creating a new route just for that.

Comment: @user2080105: because that wouldn't be RESTful anymore. Please read the guideline and you'll be finding an answer to your question yourself - and you'll realize it is matching with what Cassio posted in this answer.

Comment: Why do I need to respect RESTful if I am sure that in my situations it causes more work with no benifits

Comment: @user2080105 There's no point in asking a question if you are not open to the answers.